# How to delete lines after : if value is >5 in Notepad++ or Python

Tags: notepad++, python, regex, python3

Hoping someone can help. I'm trying to delete any string that has 5 or less chars after `:`

For example :

```
test:test
test:test12 (would be the only line kept)
cobra:abcd
```

I've tried solving it for hours using notepad++ as I'm just learning python I'm stuck, really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole lines or only what there is after colon?

Answer (score 3):

In the Notepad++ Replace dialog, use the Regular Expression `^[^:]*:.{0,5}$` as shown below:

[image: Notepad++ Replace dialog]

This Regular Expression will match the first instance of the `:` character, and ignore any that appear later in the string.

If you want to remove the entire line:

- if you don't have empty lines you need to keep, use <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Line Operations</kbd> → <kbd>Remove Empty Lines</kbd>.
- if you do have empty lines you need to keep, use `^[^:]*:.{0,5}\r?\n` instead. That will not work on the very last line, as that won't have the newline character(s). To use this, you will also need to check the `. matches newline` option next to the "Regular expression" radio button.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that we need to count all the characters after the `:` and up to the
end of the line.

Use the Find dialog, Mark tab, to *Mark All* using the Regular expression :

```
:(.+){6,}
```

This will mark all the lines you wish to keep, where we have at least 6 characters after the `:`. Verify visually that there is no error.

Then use the menu entry *Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines*.

Comment: Why `(.+){6,}` is better than just `.{6,}`?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Right - they are equivalent in this case. I used `+` by habit because it's greedy, but the `{6,}` here makes it unnecessary.